# Fetching date of high and low prices for week based on daily high low prices

Tags: python, pandas

First of all I will share objective of running python code.

1. Getting Daily High and Low Prices for a stock from Yahoo.
2. Converting the daily high and lows to Weekly High/Lows, monthly High Lows, Yearly High Lows.
3. Getting exact dates of Weekly or Monthly High Lows from a daily dataframe
4. Finally after fetching Dates for Weekly(or Monthly)High & lows, I want to arrange the data of what occured first High or Low during the week. for eg. during week ending 12th December, 2020, I get High of the week is 100 and low of week is 97(after completing step 2) and also High date and low date from daily dataframe (from step 3), I want to arrange Prices in order of occurence. so if High happened on 9th December and Low happened on 12th December. The prices will be arranged as 100 in row 1 and then 97 in row 2 and this process repeats for entire data frame.

What I have been able to achieve.
I have completed step 1 and step 2. Struggling in step for 3 as of now.

**Have accomplished Step 1 by**

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

Ticker = '^NSEI'


f = yf.download(Ticker,period="max")
f = f.drop(['Adj Close'], axis=1)
f = f.drop(['Open'], axis=1)
f = f.drop(['Close'], axis=1)
f = f.drop(['Volume'], axis=1)
f.reset_index(inplace=True)
f.insert(0,'Ticker',Ticker)
```

**Step 2 by**

```
fw = f.groupby(['Ticker', pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='W')])\
    .agg(High=pd.NamedAgg(column='High', aggfunc='max'),
         Low=pd.NamedAgg(column='Low', aggfunc='min'))\
        .reset_index()
fm = f.groupby(['Ticker', pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='M')])\
    .agg(High=pd.NamedAgg(column='High', aggfunc='max'),
         Low=pd.NamedAgg(column='Low', aggfunc='min'))\
        .reset_index()
fq = f.groupby(['Ticker', pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='Q')])\
    .agg(High=pd.NamedAgg(column='High', aggfunc='max'),
         Low=pd.NamedAgg(column='Low', aggfunc='min'))\
        .reset_index()
fy = f.groupby(['Ticker', pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='Y')])\
    .agg(High=pd.NamedAgg(column='High', aggfunc='max'),
         Low=pd.NamedAgg(column='Low', aggfunc='min'))\
        .reset_index()
```

Struggling with step 3. used pd.merge, pd.join, pd.concat but unable to combine Weekly dataframe with dataframe on Highs and lows. The no of weekly records increase by performing merge and drop duplcates also didn't work properly when specified keep last.

So if you all can help me in step 3 and 4 would be grateful. **Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

**Solved the query which i posted above. Hope this help others. Thanks**

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np


Ticker = '^NSEI'

df = yf.download(Ticker, period='max')
df= df.drop(['Open', 'Close', 'Adj Close', 'Volume'], axis = 1).reset_index()

# Daily 3238 columns for reference

#Adding columns for weekly, monthly,6 month,Yearly,
df['WkEnd'] = df.Date.dt.to_period('W').apply(lambda r: r.start_time) + dt.timedelta(days=6)
df['MEnd'] = (df.Date.dt.to_period('M').apply(lambda r: r.end_time)).dt.date
df['6Mend'] = np.where(df.Date.dt.month <= 6,(df.Date.dt.year).astype(str)+'-1H',(df['Date'].dt.year).astype(str)+'-2H')
df['YEnd'] = (df.Date.dt.to_period('Y').apply(lambda r: r.end_time)).dt.date


# key variable for melting
d = {'Date':['Hidate', 'Lodate'], 'Price':['High','Low']}

#creating weekly neoformat
dw = df.groupby(['WkEnd']).agg({'High' : 'max','Low' : 'min' }).reset_index()
dw['Hidate'] = dw[['WkEnd','High']].merge(df,how = 'left').Date
dw['Lodate'] = dw[['WkEnd','Low']].merge(df,how = 'left').Date
dw = pd.lreshape(dw,d)
dw = dw.sort_values(by = ['Date']).reset_index()
dw = dw.drop(['index'], axis = 1)

#creating Monthly neoformat
dm = df.groupby(['MEnd']).agg({'High' : 'max','Low' : 'min' }).reset_index()
dm['Hidate'] = dm[['MEnd','High']].merge(df,how = 'left').Date
dm['Lodate'] = dm[['MEnd','Low']].merge(df,how = 'left').Date
dm = pd.lreshape(dm,d)
dm = dm.sort_values(by = ['Date']).reset_index()
dm = dm.drop(['index'], axis = 1)


#creating 6mth neoformat
d6m = df.groupby(['6Mend']).agg({'High' : 'max','Low' : 'min' }).reset_index()
d6m['Hidate'] = d6m[['6Mend','High']].merge(df,how = 'left').Date
d6m['Lodate'] = d6m[['6Mend','Low']].merge(df,how = 'left').Date
d6m = pd.lreshape(d6m,d)
d6m = d6m.sort_values(by = ['Date']).reset_index()
d6m = d6m.drop(['index'], axis = 1)

#creating Yearly neoformat
dy = df.groupby(['YEnd']).agg({'High' : 'max','Low' : 'min' }).reset_index()
dy['Hidate'] = dy[['YEnd','High']].merge(df,how = 'left').Date
dy['Lodate'] = dy[['YEnd','Low']].merge(df,how = 'left').Date
dy = pd.lreshape(dy,d)
dy = dy.sort_values(by = ['Date']).reset_index()
dy = dy.drop(['index'], axis = 1)
```